# How to call specific function for a global class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm, cloudkit

I have some Realm models in my app that all use a base class. In this class I wrote some generic functions like the one below:

```
- (void)save {
    self.updatedAt = [NSDate date];
    [self.realm beginWriteTransaction];
    [self.realm addOrUpdateObject:self];
    [self.realm commitWriteTransaction];
    [[SyncEngine sharedInstance] store:self];
}
```

Now, I also wrote a class called `SyncEngine`, which checks if some available synchronization methods are enabled and then calls them:

```
- (void)store:(id)object {
    if ([Preferences CloudKitEnabled]) {
        [self.cloudKit store:object];
    }
}
```

This is where my problem arises. I have written a base class called `CloudKitManager` which has some generic functions. I then create a specific `CloudKitClass` for every model in my app, so I'll end up with `CloudKitRestaurant` and `CloudKitTable`. All of these will contain a function `(void)store:(id)sender`. What would be the best way to call the store function of a specific CloudKit class, based on the class that is being stored in Realm?

Ideally, I'd like for `RLMRestaurant` to automatically use `CloudKitRestaurant` and not have to use and if else or switch statement.

For further clarity, this is how `SyncEngine` works.

```
@interface SyncEngine()

@property (nonatomic, strong) CloudKitManager *cloudKitManager;

@end

@implementation SyncEngine

static SyncEngine *sharedInstance = nil;

+ (SyncEngine *)sharedInstance {

    if (sharedInstance == nil) {
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
    }
    return sharedInstance;
}

- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.cloudKitManager = [[CloudKitManager alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: Where do you keep `CloudKitRestaurant` object?

Comment: It's just an `NSObject`.

Comment: Yes, i mean where do you keep this object. Inside `CloudKitManager` or `SyncEngine` ...

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I misunderstood. It's a child of `CloudKitManager`, so it's its own thing.

Comment: Ok, i got it. What is relationship between `CloudKitManager` and `SyncEngine`?

Comment: `CloudKitManager` is one of the possible services `SyncEngine` embodies. I'll add how it's structured to the post.

Comment: I'm confused here. You have only a `CloudKitManager` object inside `SyncEngine`. Where is another `CloudKitManager` child class? Where is your `if else or switch statement` if you have to use it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160376/discussion-between-user4992124-and-trungduc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, you should keep type of `CloudKitManager` class inside `RLMBase` object. And when you need to call `[[CloudKitManager sharedInstance] store:object]`, call `[[object.cloudKitClass sharedInstance] store:object]`.

Try my code below.

```
@interface RLMBase : NSObject

- (Class)cloudKitClass;

@end

@implementation RLMBase

- (Class)cloudKitClass {
  // Must be overridden in subclass.
  return CloudKitManager.class;
}

@end

@interface RLMRestaurant : RLMBase

@end

@implementation RLMRestaurant

- (Class)cloudKitClass {
  return CloudKitRestaurant.class;
}

@end

- (void)store:(RLMBase *)object {
  if ([Preferences CloudKitEnabled]) {
    [[object.cloudKitClass sharedInstance] store:object];
  }
}
```

**ANOTHER WAY**

Put `store:` method from `SyncEngine` to `RLMBase` object.

```
@interface RLMBase : NSObject

- (Class)cloudKitClass;
- (void)store;

@end

@implementation RLMBase

- (Class)cloudKitClass {
  // Must be overridden in subclass.
  return CloudKitManager.class;
}

- (void)store {
  if ([Preferences CloudKitEnabled]) {
    [[self.cloudKitClass sharedInstance] store:self];
  }
}

@end
```

And `save` method will become

```
- (void)save {
  self.updatedAt = [NSDate date];
  [self.realm beginWriteTransaction];
  [self.realm addOrUpdateObject:self];
  [self.realm commitWriteTransaction];
  [self store];
}
```